# Sort Multiple Dataframes with function

Tags: r, function, sorting, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes (i.e. D1, D2, D3). They each have varying colnames, which i want to sort. But i want to create a function.

For example, D1 has the following columns in this order = strawberry, apple, banana

D2 has the following columns in this order = x2, x4, x3
etc. 
Here is what i am trying to tweak:

```
Column_Sort = function(data) {

data = data[,sort(columnnames(data)]

return data}
```

Is there a way i can 
1) create a function the will sort 
2) be able to sort multiple data sets at once and return it

I know i can do it one by one, but i have multiple datasets, that I would like to do at once.

Comment: You can create a function that takes data and column names that you would like to sort.

Comment: You can put all your data frames in a list and use `lapply()` to apply your function to all the data frames in one go.

Comment: `new <- list(iris, mtcars);  lapply(new, function(x){x <- x[,sort(colnames(x))]})`

Answer (score 1):

As you state, you have 2 goals: 1) Sort *1* data frame, and 2) repeat the operation on multiple data frames. This is a good separation which allows you to develop a solution first for 1), and then for 2).

Your function is almost in place. To get the column names, use `colnames`. Secondly, R functions do not require a `return` statement, but simply return the last value. This is also a very common style guide (at least within the tidyverse packages). All in all, your function becomes:

```
sortdf <- function(data) {
  data[,sort(colnames(data))]
}
```

For 2), you can either bundle all your data frames into a list and then use lapply:

```
lapply(list(D1, D2, D3), sortdf)
```

or you can create a second function that does this for your. Either way, you have to decide how you want your *output*, as both `lapply` and a function can only return a single object - both we can bundle any number of tings into a single `list` object. So let's take the lapply and wrap it into a function:

```
sorter <- function(...) {
  lapply(list(...), sortdf)
}
```

Here, we use the ellipses `...` as a stand-in for any number of arguments the user might want to throw at the function. This would ideally be any number of data.frame. To handle a variable size set of variables, we pack it into a list. The command `list(...)` would generate a list with the *exact same* arguments as we called `sorter` with. So, go ahead and examine the output from `sorter`.

The only issue is that the returned list is unnamed. What did you put into which argument? I present here an extended version which names the output. Examine it and see if you understand what happens.

```
sorter <- function(...) {
  m <- match.call()
  ret <- lapply(list(...), sortdf)
  if (is.null(names(ret))) {
    names(ret) <- make.names(m[-1])
  } else {
    names(ret)[names(ret) == ''] <- make.names(m[-1])[names(ret) == '']
  }
  ret
}

data("mtcars")
D1 <- mtcars[,c('cyl','drat','wt','am','qsec')]
sorter(D1, mtcars)
sorter(D1, b=data.frame(b='b',a='a'))
```